# How do I get a list of checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Javascript to create an HTML form with some radio button questions and one checkbox question at the end. The reason I am using JavaScript is that the questions take data from a google cloud firestore database, and they need to be dynamic. when I get the data from the radio buttons, it shows it as a string, but when I get the data from the checkboxes, it leaves it blank. I want it to show a string with a list of boxes checked. Here is my code:

```
const OACanList = document.querySelector('#OAInput');
const setupOACans = (data) => {
  let html = '';
  if (data.length) {
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const OACan = doc.data();
        const li = `
        <style>
        #OAInput [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
            position: static;
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: initial;
        }
        </style>
          <input type="checkbox" name="OAElection" value="${OACan.name}" style="display:block opacity:1;">${OACan.name}
          <br>
        `;
        html += li
    });
    OACanList.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
      OACanList.innerHTML = html;
  };
};
```

index.js:

```
 const voteForm = document.querySelector('#vote-form');
  voteForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      db.collection('ballots').add({
          OA: voteForm.OAElection.value
        }).then(() => {
          const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-vote');
          M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
          voteForm.reset();
      }).then(() => {
        const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid);
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            doc.data().count++;
        })
      });
  });
```

Comment: What is the ouput you get when you `console.log(OACan)` ?

Comment: I get the names of the candidates from the database, but that's not the problem. It gets the names from the database successfully, but when submitted, it adds an empty field to the database.